# multiple connections without multithreading socket

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, addressbook

i've got a problem with client/server address book.
When i connect the first client all is okay. After, the server accept other connections from other clients but it doesn't respond to any request (adding numbers etc...)  what can i do?  thank you

```
int optval;
socklen_t optlen = sizeof(optval);
char choice[MAX];
char buff[MAX]; /* dati di invio e ricezione */
char buff1[MAX];
char buffNome[MAX];
char buffCognome[MAX];
char buffTelefono[MAX];
char buffMail[MAX];
struct sockaddr_in server_addr; /* indirizzo del server */
struct sockaddr_in client_addr; /* indirizzo del client */
int sd_server, sd_client; /* i socket descriptor usati per identificare server e client */


if((sd_server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    printf("Errore nella creazione del server\n");





optval = 1;
optlen = sizeof(optval);
if(setsockopt(sd_server, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, optlen) < 0) {
  perror("setsockopt()");
  close(sd_server);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; /* la famiglia dei protocolli */
server_addr.sin_port = htons(1745); /* la porta in ascolto */
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; /* dato che è un server bisogna associargli l'indirizzo della macchina su cui sta girando */


if(bind(sd_server, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0)
    printf("Errore di binding\n");




listen (sd_server, 20);

int address_size = sizeof(client_addr); 

struct elemento *lista = NULL;
struct elementoutente *listautente = NULL;

  while (1) {
if((sd_client = accept(sd_server, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &address_size)) < 0)
    printf("Errore nella chiamata accept\n");




while(1){

.... CODE.....


}
close(sd_server);
```

Comment: Why can't you use threads? If you really can't, you need to investigate non-blocking mode and the `select()` function.

Comment: because my professor don't want multithread inside this program, sigh :-(

Comment: Then you need to get him to define the problem more adequately, and also the expected solution space. Either (i) the program isn't supposed to handle more than one client at a time, (ii) you are supposed to use threads, (iii) you are supposed to use `select()`, or (iv) you are using a Unix variant and you are expected to fork a new process per `accept()`. Ask him.

Comment: i don't undestand why same sockets can't be used for transferring data between server/clients  :S

Comment: Each socket is the endpoint of a connection. Each connection is to a unique client. This question is rapidly approaching 'not real'.

Comment: The question is real allright. Dealing with threads is downright dangerous and fork, while safe, can be complex. You do need multiple sockets, but you don't need multiple streams of execution as long as you close the socket after each request.

Comment: Your fears are misplaced. Dealing with threads is routine, not 'downright dangerous' at all. I've been doing for 23 years. There is nothing 'complex' about fork() either: it could hardly be simpler actually. However, as I suggested, the issue here was clearly getting the requirement straight. (i) above was right on the money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get away with no thread/forking if you only process one client request and then return to accept loop. In other words, get rid of the inner while(1) loop. Make sure that your clients open socket, make one request, then close socket (that's normal operation for HTTP 1.0).

This is quite inefficient, but it will get you going.

Comment: thank you to EJP and Arkadiy, only the multithreading was blacklisted, i've used a fork :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make your listening socket on which you call accept as non-blocking.
Make all the connected client sockets also non-blocking.
Use a top-level select/poll/epoll on all these sockets.
Whenever there is an event on the connected sockets, or a client is waiting to connect on the listening socket, you will get a notification. Handle that notification.
This is an efficient method to use one process only without getting into fork or multi-threading for separate client handlers.